# One to many inner join

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So, my problem is. I have table payment and table charge, so, one payment have many charge but one charge have one payment. I need select all payment where all charge sum for one payment != all charge for one payment.

Example of code

```
select payment_account, payment_agreement, payment_pay, payment_charge
from payment join
     charge
     on payment_id = charge_payment_id
where charge_summ != payment_charge
group by payment_id;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be very helpful.

Comment: one payment have column charge_summ, so, I need select all payments whrere charge_summ != all payment_charge for that payment. payment_charge is column in charge

Answer (score 0):

You maybe can do it without a join, just with a sub select to get the summ of the payment_charge and compare it with the charge_summ of each payment:

```
select payment_account, payment_agreement, payment_pay, payment_charge
from payment 
where payment.charge_summ <> (select sum(payment_charge)
                        from charge 
                        where payment.payment_id = charge_payment_id)
```

**EDIT**
You can do it to with JOIN and without inner select:

```
select payment_id,payment_account, payment_agreement, payment_pay, charge_summ,sum(payment_charge) 
from payment join
     charge
     on payment_id = charge_payment_id
group by payment_id,payment_account, payment_agreement, payment_pay,charge_summ
having charge_summ <> sum(payment_charge)
```

Comment: maybe this task decide without inner select?

Answer (score 0):

Table structure will be usefull in any case, try this query:

```
select payment_account, payment_agreement, payment_pay, payment_charge
from payment join
(select charge_payment_id, sum(payment_charge) as totally from charge group by 
charge_payment_id) A 
on payment_id = charge_payment_id and payment_charge != totally;
```

Here you first sum the charges and compare with the results.